# Flash not properly showing in internet explorer

Tags: flash

Happy New Year to All Of U.

In my Flash Page,Image to be flashed.It is properly working in Crome & mozila firefox.But in Internet Explorer, its width is less to that actual width.

here is that flash coding.

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" width="401" height="107" align="middle">
                  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                  <param name="movie" value="myalbum.swf?xml_path=default.xml" />
                  <param name="quality" value="high" />
                  <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                  <embed src="myalbum.swf?xml_path=default.xml" quality="high" width="401" height="107" align="middle" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" wmode="transparent" />                
</object>
```

in default.xml ,external images to be uploaded of width 401px & 107px.

Is there any changes to be done for Interner Explorer ?
Please help me.
Thanks .

Comment: Since IE only reads the <object>, but not the <embed> tags - have you tried to remove all the whitespace and keep the code in a single line?

Answer (score 0):

weltraumpirat gave a good advice. But you do not need to put everything in a single line, you can break the line inside the tag, like this:

```
<div
    ><object ...
        ><param ...
        /><embed...
        /></object
    ></div
>
```

Also, browsers have different default values for margins and paddings. You should look for a css reset. More info on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500827/css-tips-which-every-beginning-developer-should-know-about/501098#501098

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) for embedding swf movies into your html page.
It is an open source library that takes care of everything for you.

There is also a [generator](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/downloads/detail?name=swfobject_generator_1_2_html.zip&can=2&q=) that can help you define the right html template for embedding your swf.

Cheers